# JS: using ajax to check existing data in db on input typing

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

So I want to detect if the value a user is typing in an input exists in the database, if so, display an error message. I've gotten pretty close except when the input is empty, the empty value is being submitted instead of what is GOING to be typed.

```
 $("#email").on("blur", function(){
        var val = $(this).val(), id = $("#id").val();
        $.ajax({
            method: 'GET',
            url: '/msg',
            data: {
                action: "check_title",
                email: val,
                id: id
            },
            success: function(data) {
                $(".error-msg").text(data);
            }
        })
    });
```

I've also tried one with a `keyup` function and it's still doing the same, evaluating the empty field. How can I have it so it's constantly evaluating what is being typed?

Comment: can you not just exit early if the value is empty?

Answer (score 1):

This snippet creates an input with the id of "in" and checks if there is something in in's value. I guess that is answering your question a bit more specifically. And thanks "Jeff Puckett II" for pointing this out.

```js
$('#in').on('input focusout', function(){
  var val = $('#in').val();
  if (val != ""){
    console.log('someones typing');
  } else {
    console.log('empty');
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <input id="in" type="text">
  </body>
```

try `.on('input')` instead of `.on('blur')`

```
$("#email").on("input", function(){//do something});
```

Comment: for `constantly evaluating what is being typed` this is good. to answer the question, would still need a way to check if the value was empty before `do something`

Answer (score 1):

Along the same lines as Jeff Puckett's answer, I would perform the empty test and return an instructional message if empty:

```
$("#email").on("blur", function(){
    var val = $(this).val(), id = $("#id").val();
    if (val.length < 1 || val==""){
        alert('Please complete all fields');
        $('#email').css('background','yellow').focus();
        return false;
    }
    $.ajax({
        method: 'GET',
        url: '/msg',
        data: {
            action: "check_title",
            email: val,
            id: id
        },
        success: function(data) {
            $(".error-msg").text(data);
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    //in your function just add 
    if(!val) {
      $(".error-msg").text("Empty!");
    }
    //or
   if(val) {
      //your ajax code
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

simply check if input is empty first

```
 $("#email").on("blur", function(){
        var val = $(this).val(), id = $("#id").val();
        // check if val is empty
        if (val != "")
        $.ajax({
            method: 'GET',
            url: '/msg',
            data: {
                action: "check_title",
                email: val,
                id: id
            },
            success: function(data) {
                $(".error-msg").text(data);
            }
        })
    });
```

Answer (score -1):

use this:

```
$('input').keyup(function(){ 
   console.log($(this).val());
});
```

keyup or keydown to get data every time when a user type in the focused input.

Comment: how will this check if the input is empty?

Comment: Are you stupid to press -1, but not thining - If($this).va() == "" )// do something?

Comment: @gdfgdfg First, do not call names on StackOverflow. Second, you have no way of knowing who pressed downvote -- it was probably not Jeff. On this site, you will be downvoted frequently, both justly and injustly. If you stoop to name calling, you will be further downvoted. Like with the rest of life, just roll with it.